# Error when running Matlab script in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to run a Matlab script in Visual Studio C# Windows Application. I have run the Matlab Compiler to build my script and obtained the dll (tryingLF). Below is my code for trying to run the script when I click on a button in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using tryingLF;      //dll

namespace LinkMatlabandC
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Class1 linking = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            linking = new Class1();
            linking.loadForecast();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
}
}
```

However, when I tried to run the C# program, I got an error called "The type initializer for 'tryingLF.Class1' threw an exception."
Why is this so? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ex.InnerException` property and it should have more details on what exactly is causing the type initialization exception.

One possibility is that Class1 needs some **stuff** to get initialized and it cannot find one of them. so it goes crazy.